# AJAX Successful redirects but gives [object : object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have used my `node.js` method `getDetails` and provide one static id. But data  results as object. When I check my `node.js` method from postman it provide JSON string but AJAX successful data is provide object dont no why??

```js
$.post("/salons/getDetails",
{
    objectId: "561cd801a4b2b6ec1dafba23"
},
function(data)
{
    alert(1);
    alert(data);
});

});
```

```js
My backend method is 

router.post('/getDetails',function(req,res){
    data=req.body;
    var objectId=data.objectId;
    salon.find({ "_id": objectId }).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alert only outputs strings, therefore you either use `console.log` allowing you to see its contents in the console, or use `JSON.stringify(data)` to convert your JSON object into a string.

Comment: Thanx its working for me

Comment: Sorry to ask but is something wrong with your `E` on the keyboard? First "objact" and now this.

Comment: no its not but objact is typed in hurry by mistakes as its my first question on stack overflow and my work is not getting done so in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a JSON object. Try putting a `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data);`. Or if you want to keep the alert, try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` and see what it returns.